# Centering Table Header Text In Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to center the text in my table header to align with the text below. I just cannot seem to get the header to align.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="text-center">
    <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum
    </p>
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Table Header 1
            </th>
            <th>Table Header 2
            </th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Lorem Ipsum
            </td>
            <td>Lorem Ipsum
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`class="text-center"` will work for this but strangely enough you need to target the `<th>` elements directly instead of placing it on the `<tr>` parent element.

According to [this question](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/16146), the following is why text-center does not affect `<thead>` when applied to the `<table>` element:

> We set `th { text-center: left; }`, which is more specific than the
>   class on the parent  and thus prevents the header cell from
>   inheriting the centering styles. Putting the `.text-center` class
>   directly on the `<th>` should work though **(confirmed in the docs)**.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="text-center">
    <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum
    </p>
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="text-center">Table Header 1
            </th>
            <th class="text-center">Table Header 2
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Lorem Ipsum
            </td>
            <td>Lorem Ipsum
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks Master Yoda!  Works like a charm.